# PHP - create dynamic functions in foreach without a class

Tags: php

I use WooCommerce Tabs to dynamically show tabs regarding of the variable products that are available:

```
foreach ($variant_attributes as $variant_id => $variant_attribute) {
    $tabs[$variant_attribute['attribute_art']] = [
        'title'    => $variant_attribute['attribute_art'],
        'priority' => 16,
        'callback' => 'custom_tab_content_'.$variant_attribute['attribute_art']
    ];
}
```

As the Woocommerce tabs needs a callback to show data in the tab, I need to create functions dynamically like I tried here in this example, but of course this does not work.

How can I provide a callback here that is created in the foreach loop?

So for example if `$variant_attribute['attribute_art']` is `variant_1` the function I need is called `custom_tab_content_variant_1`.

Thanks for your help!

**Edit:**

The solution is:

```
foreach ($variant_attributes as $variant_id => $variant_attribute) {

    $tabs[$variant_attribute['attribute_art']] = [
        'title'    => $variant_attribute['attribute_art'],
        'priority' => 16,
        'variant_id' => $variant_id,
        'callback' => function($arg, $params) {

            echo $params['variant_id'];
        }
    ];
}
```

Comment: Closures, ... `function($arg){ ...}`  That said, it would be better to make one function and reference it in all of them, if they have the same functionality.  If not, stop being lazy.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix ? What do you mean? How does this help in creating dynamic functions?

Comment: `How can I provide a callback here that is created in the foreach loop`  Look at example #2 http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here as I cant put it in a comment.

```
foreach ($variant_attributes as $variant_id => $variant_attribute) {
    $tabs[$variant_attribute['attribute_art']] = [
        'title'    => $variant_attribute['attribute_art'],
        'priority' => 16,
        'callback' => function($arg1){
               //do stuff
         }
    ];
}
```

Of course if the functionality is different, then you have no choice but to write them separately.

However, even if it is not then you should do it in the traditional way.

If its in a class

```
 class foo{
     public function register(){
         foreach ($variant_attributes as $variant_id => $variant_attribute) {
             $tabs[$variant_attribute['attribute_art']] = [
                'title'    => $variant_attribute['attribute_art'],
                'priority' => 16,
                'callback' => [$this, 'action']
            ];
         }
     }

     public function action($arg1){

     }
  }
```

See the fist one created (n) functions that are all the same, the second one creates 1 function/method uses it (n) times

Or you can write them by hand, and assign them in a loop like you are.  You can't/shouldn't create functions in a loop.

```
  function custom_tab_content_variant_1($arg1){

  }
```

This last way, created 1 function uses it 1 time, or you can create (n) functions by hand and use them each 1 time.

Comment: Thanks! It's a bit silly, because I tried it with the anonymous function before and this did not work. Now it works somehow. Maybe I messed something up. If I have the $arg1 within my function, it shows me the title. Do I have a chance to get the $variant_id inside my anonymous function?

Comment: probably, you can always do `print_r(func_get_args());` to see.....  http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php  Although I would put them in like `function($arg1,$arg2){...}` etc....

Comment: I figured it out. I just need to include it in the $tabs array. Thanks for your help! Have a nice day!